# Struggling with BFGS minimization algorithm for Logistic regression in Clojure with Incanter

Tags: clojure, statistics, machine-learning, incanter, logistic-regression

I'm trying to implement a simple logistic regression example in Clojure using the [Incanter data analysis](https://github.com/liebke/incanter) library. I've successfully coded the Sigmoid and Cost functions, but Incanter's BFGS minimization function seems to be causing me quite some trouble.

```
(ns ml-clj.logistic
  (:require [incanter.core :refer :all]
            [incanter.optimize :refer :all]))


(defn sigmoid
  "compute the inverse logit function, large positive numbers should be
close to 1, large negative numbers near 0,
z can be a scalar, vector or matrix.
sanity check: (sigmoid 0) should always evaluate to 0.5"
  [z]
  (div 1 (plus 1 (exp (minus z)))))

(defn cost-func
  "computes the cost function (J) that will be minimized
   inputs:params theta X matrix and Y vector"
  [X y]
  (let
      [m (nrow X)
       init-vals (matrix (take (ncol X) (repeat 0)))
       z (mmult X init-vals)
       h (sigmoid z)
       f-half (mult (matrix (map - y)) (log (sigmoid (mmult X init-vals))))
       s-half (mult (minus 1 y) (log (minus 1 (sigmoid (mmult X init-vals)))))
       sub-tmp (minus f-half s-half)
       J (mmult (/ 1 m) (reduce + sub-tmp))]
    J))
```

When I try `(minimize (cost-func X y) (matrix [0 0]))` giving `minimize` a function and starting params the REPL throws an error.

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: optimize$minimize  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

I'm very confused as to what exactly the minimize function is expecting.

For reference, I rewrote it all in python, and all of the code runs as expected, using the same minimization algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
data = np.loadtxt('testSet.txt', delimiter='\t')

X = data[:,0:2]
y = data[:, 2]


def sigmoid(X):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.e**(-1.0 * X))

def compute_cost(theta, X, y):
    m = y.shape[0]
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta.T))
    J = y.T.dot(np.log(h)) + (1.0 - y.T).dot(np.log(1.0 - h))
    cost = (-1.0 / m) * J.sum() 
    return cost

def fit_logistic(X,y):
    initial_thetas = np.zeros((len(X[0]), 1))
    myargs = (X, y)
    theta = sp.optimize.fmin_bfgs(compute_cost, x0=initial_thetas,
                                     args=myargs)
    return theta
```

outputting

```
Current function value: 0.594902
         Iterations: 6
         Function evaluations: 36
         Gradient evaluations: 9
array([ 0.08108673, -0.12334958])
```

I don't understand why the Python code can run successfully, but my Clojure implementation fails. Any suggestions?

**Update**

rereading the docstring for `minimize` i've been trying to calculate the derivative of `cost-func` which throws a new error.

```
(def grad (gradient cost-func (matrix [0 0])))
(minimize cost-func (matrix [0 0]) (grad (matrix [0 0]) X))
ExceptionInfo throw+: {:exception "Matrices of different sizes cannot be differenced.", :asize [2 1], :bsize [1 2]}  clatrix.core/- (core.clj:950)
```

using `trans` to convert the 1xn col matrix to a nx1 row matrix just yields the same error with opposite errors.

`:asize [1 2], :bsize [2 1]}`

I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: 1) Why `(minimize (cost-func X y) (matrix [0 0]))`? The first arg should be `cost-func` instead of `(cost-func X y)`. 2) you should give a `f-prime` as the third arg.

Comment: ok, but where do I pass in my data then? the python equivalent has an `args` param for me to pass in my training data. I don't see anything like that in the docstring for `minimize`.

Comment: you can use a closure

Answer (score 3):

I can't say anything about your implementation, but [incanter.optimize/minimize](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/modules/incanter-core/src/incanter/optimize.clj#L767) expects (at least) three parameters and you're giving it only two:

```
Arguments:
  f -- Objective function. Takes a collection of values and returns a scalar
       of the value of the function.
  start -- Collection of initial guesses for the minimum
  f-prime -- partial derivative of the objective function. Takes
             a collection of values and returns a collection of partial
             derivatives with respect to each variable. If this is not
             provided it will be estimated using gradient-fn.
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to tell you directly what to supply (for `f-prime`?) here but maybe someone else is. Btw, I think the `ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to [...]` is actually quite helpful here.

**Edit:** Actually, I think the docstring above is not correct, since the source code does not use `gradient-fn` to estimate `f-prime`. Maybe, you can use `incanter.optimize/gradient` to generate your own?

Comment: thanks for the tip! I edited my original post with an attempt to use `gradient` to calculate the derivative. That itself causes another misalignment with the matrices. this is turning out to be a rather frustrating rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

First, Your cost function should have a parameter for theta like your python implementation however your implementation has fixed as initial-value.

Second, if your cost-func is correct, then you can call optimize like this

```
(optimize (fn [theta] (cost-func theta X y)) [0 0 0])
```

Hope this can help you.